# Confusion between vector space, field and sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, vector-spaces, terminology, definition, finite-fields

From my understanding, a vector space is a set that is closed under addition and multiplication, so let $A$ denote a set, a vector space $V = (A, +, \times)$

But whenever you read the definition of vector space, it always says something like: "Suppose $V$ is a vector space over the field of ...."

But I thought a vector space is defined in terms of sets, not fields!

Can someone help me resolve this confusion?

Comment: If interested, look up what a module is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, a field $F$ has addition and multiplication between members of $F$ (and has a $0$ and a $1$, etc. plus all the axioms).

A vector space is a set $V$ with addition of members of $V$ (which is an Abelian group, so has a $0$ etc.), and there is also a field $F$ (the field *over* which we have the vector space) and an extra multiplication called *scalar* multiplication (scalars are members of $F$) defined as a map $F \times V \rightarrow V$ that satisfies some axioms.

If $F$ is a field itself, we can use $F = V$ and see $F$ as a vector space over itself, using standard multiplication as scalar multiplication. So we can see $\mathbb{R}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, but also over $\mathbb{Q}$ (much more interesting!). But in general, $V$ (the vectors) is not a field (only addition is present), but there is a scalar field $F$ (that has to be specified as well) with an extra "cross-domain" multiplication. For the plane we can multiply a point by a number, stretching each coordinate ($a(x,y) = (ax,ay)$, which defines multiplication of $a \in \mathbb{R}$ with $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$), which is a standard example. The whole of linear algebra is about vector spaces.

In more formal terms: a vector space $V$ over the field $F$ (with its own addition and multiplication $+$ and $\ast$ and its own 0,1) is a tuple $(V,F,+,\times,0)$ where $+ : V \times V \rightarrow V$, $\times: F \times V \rightarrow V$ and $(V,+,0)$ is an Abelian group, and we have the additional axioms (universal quantifiers implied): $a \times (x + y) = a\times x + a \times y$, $(a+b) \times x = a \times x + b \times x$, $1 \times x = x$, $(a \ast b) \times x = a \times (b \times x)$.

Comment: Is it possible to express vector field in terms of $( \cdot, \cdot, \cdot)$ to make the structure clearer, something like....an inner product space is $(V, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle)$

Comment: A vector field is a special function from a set $S$ to some vector space $V$, with possibly extra structure. It does not really fit this format like a purely algebraic structure.

Comment: Sorry I meant a vector space (not vector field). Is it possible to express a vector space in terms of $(\cdot, \cdot, \cdot)$?

Comment: @MathNewb I added a formal definition.

Comment: It is now perfectly clear, but is there opportunity to distinguish between the vector space $V$ and the $V$ which is used in the tuple $(V, F, +, \times, 0)$? In the tuple, $V$ is just a set, which is not the vector space itself, so would it be more appropriate to distinguish the vector space $V$ and the set $V$ as used in the tuple?

Comment: @MathNewb It is just an abuse: the vector space is actually the data of **the entire tuple**, but we refers to it as just the underlying set $V$. Do really want to say that the real plane is $(\mathbb R^2, \mathbb R, +_{\mathbb R^2}, (t,(x,y))\mapsto (tx,ty),(0,0))$ or just say $\mathbb R^2$? I, personnaly, prefer the second...

Answer (score 4):

Vector spaces are not sets closed under addition and multiplication. Those are sets $A$ which are coupled with a field $F$, and with a binary operator called addition $+$, and with scalar multiplication when the scalar is from $F$. And we require that these operations satisfy certain properties.

In general there is no "internal" multiplication on vector spaces. You can only multiply something by a scalar which sits "outside" the vector space.

Comment: Hi can you please illustrate an example of a "set coupled with a field"? For example, $R$ is a vector space, real numbers can be thought as vectors, in this case, all I can see is a field, I can't see the set structure

Comment: $\Bbb R^6$ is a vector space *over* $\Bbb R$. When you talk about multiplication, you are talking about multiplying a scalar $r$ from $\Bbb R$ by a vector $v$ from $\Bbb R^6$.